# Conditional probability of Exp() distributed random variables.

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

The life of a repairing device is Exp(1/a)-distributed. Peter wishes to use
it on n different, independent, Exp(1/na)-distributed occasions.

(a) Compute the probability Pn that this is possible.

(b) Determine the limit of Pn as $n \to \infty$

. Part (b) is easy if you have (a), which should be $( \frac{n}{n+1})^n$

My first source of confusion is $Exp(\frac{1}{an})$. So this should be $(an)e^{-anx}$ ? I'm guessing that we need to "condition" on this and I get something  like:

$$ \int_0^\infty ( a e^{-ax})(an e^{-anx} ) dx  = \frac{a^2 n}{a+an} = \frac{an}{1+n}$$

which at least looks somewhat like the answer, though it completely wrong. I have no clue how the occasions can be continuously Exp distributed if "n" should be a discrete quantity.

Comment: A random variable that is Exp($\lambda$) has PDF $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x \geq 0$.  So if $\lambda = 1/a$ we get PDF $(1/a)e^{-x/a}$ for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: PS: I had trouble interpreting the question, I think it means $\{X_i\}$ are iid repair times and $\{Y_i\}$ are independent and  iid other times, you want to find  $P[\cap_{i=1}^n \{X_i \leq Y_i\}]$.  That answer indeed comes out to $(n/(n+1))^n$.  Intuitively, the $a$ parameter is like a "speedup" switch that makes the experiments run faster but does not affect their outcomes.

Comment: @Michael Thank you! The way you described the problem makes much more sense. So does the fact about "a". Tough it makes conceptual sense, I feel no closer to a solution. I've just been starting at this problem for six hours today. It's ridiculous.

Comment: What is giving you further trouble?  The integral you set up is (almost) the way to go, except you need to get teh correct $\lambda$, and it looks like you are computing $P[Y<X]$ rather than $P[X<Y]$.  It would help to specify the equation you are using to get that integral.  For example, are you using an integral version of hte law of total probability ?

Comment: @Michael  yes, I was trying to use the law of total probability. I see my error with $\lambda$ now, though I didn't realize I was computing a reversed version of what I needed.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you like, based on the above comments.  (That is standard for this website for people who can solve a question based on hints in comments).  You might want to first use language of general $X$ and $Y$, like $P[X\leq Y] = \int...$ (where the integral involves expressions with $X$ and $Y$ , like distributions or PDFs), to make sure you are doing steps correctly.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
P(X<Y_1) &= \iint_{(x, y):\,y \geq x} f_{XY}(x, y) \;dydx \\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(y)\;dydx \\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{a}e^{\frac{-x}{a}} \frac{1}{na}e^{\frac{-x}{na}}\;dydx \\
&= \frac{1}{na^2}\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty e^{\frac{-x}{a}} e^{\frac{-y}{na}}\;dydx \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \int_0^\infty e^{\frac{-x}{a}} e^{\frac{-x}{na}}\;dydx \\
&= \frac{1}{a}(0+\frac{1}{\frac{n+1}{na}}) \\
&= \frac{n}{n+1}.
\end{align*}
And so for all $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n$, we get that $P_n$ is
$$P_n = \Big(\frac{n}{n+1})^n.$$